# ShareThis image share not working on Facebook/Twitter

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, sharethis

ShareThis image share not working on Facebook/Twitter on PHP site I am using the ShareThis plugin on a PHP-based site that involved image upload and processing. I want to allow people to share the final processed image, along with a link to the page.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="title">
    <h1> South Florida Speaks</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" id="paragraph">
    <div class="row">
      <p>The South Florida Speaks series is put on by LaunchCode to highlight the variety of programming languages used by local employers and entreprenurs in the local area. </p>
      <br>
      <p>Miami is well known for being multicultural; many people speak a second or third language. We want to make saying "I speak JavaScript" or "I speak .NET" just as common as telling someone that you speak Spanish or Creole.</p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <em>
          <a href="#" class="inline-link lc">Check out our list of upcoming events</a>!
        </em>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="finalImgContainer">
      <?php
        if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "submit") {
          echo  '<div class="row" id="finalImage">
                  <img src= "';
          $imageUrl = 'resources/uploads/' . session_id() . '/' . basename( $imageWithText );
          echo $imageUrl;
          echo '"><div>';
          echo "<div class='row' id='shareThisRow'><span class='st_sharethis' st_url='http://www.sfspeaks.com/{$imageUrl}' st_title='South Florida Speaks' st_image='http://www.sfspeaks.com/{$imageUrl}' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
          <span class='st_facebook' displayText='Facebook'></span>
          <span class='st_twitter' displayText='Tweet'></span>
          <span class='st_linkedin' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
          <span class='st_pinterest' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
          <span class='st_email' displayText='Email'></span></div>";

          // echo "<div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='23146239' data-title='South Florida Speaks' data-link='http://www.sfspeaks.com/' data-image='http://www.sfspeaks.com/{$imageUrl}' data-summary='Description of the page you are sharing'></div>";
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```